# Formula Converted into Code and why locked CellA10

Tags: excel, vba

I have wrote a formula and convert my formula to Code. Where i have been facing an issue.

When i manually write the formula in cell G10 and drag it down it works perfectly. Then converted the formula to code where Cell A10 `MATCH(A10,Table1!$6:$6,0)` is got locked which should be changed according to the cell reference.

here is attached picture

[image]

It should be lik

```
A10
A11
A12
A13
A14
A15

=IFERROR(INDEX(Table1!$A$1:$DP$27,MATCH($G$9&$E$4,Table1!$E:$E&Table1!$F:$F,0),MATCH(A10,Table1!$6:$6,0)), "")
```

Your help will be highly appreciated.

code

```
Dim LastRowColumnA As Long
LastRowColumnA = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
Sheet1.Range("G10:G" & LastRowColumnA).FormulaArray = _
        "=IFERROR(INDEX(Table1!R1C1:R27C120,MATCH(R9C7&R4C5,Table1!C5&Table1!C6,0),MATCH(RC[-6],Table1!R6,0)), """")"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Sheet1.Range("G10").FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(INDEX(Table1!R1C1:R27C120,MATCH(R9C7&R4C5,Table1!C5&Table1!C6,0),MATCH(RC[-6],Table1!R6,0)), """")"
Sheet1.Range("G10").AutoFill Destination:=Sheet1.Range("G10:G" & LastRowColumnA), Type:=xlFillDefault
```